# Use data generated at the end of a Javascript function in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, asynchronous, save

I have made a site that loads data from a file (a time value), then starts a (Javascript) timer. I would then like to use php to add the time recorded on to the loaded time, so you effectively have an incremental timer that carries on from the last time I visited. This saving of the new time value could be done by a Javascript function feeding into PHP (I assume this needs AJAX, and I haven't figured out how to get that to work), or by going to a new PHP page with all the saving instructions there, but in this case how do I carry over the data from the Javascript timer? Are there any other methods to do this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way would be to send the data to the server everytime the timer ticks and retrieve it later.
This is how to do it using [jQuery](http://jquery.com/):

Sending the data:

```
$.post("time.php", { 
    time:"<TIME HERE>" 
});
```

Getting the data

```
$.get("time.php", function(data) {
    //start your timer here (data is the time)
});
```

And the PHP code (time.php):

```
<?php
session_start(); //Start the session  

if($_POST['time'] $_SESSION['time'] = $_POST['time']; //If the time was sent, save it to session

echo $_SESSION['time']; //Output the saved time
?>
```

Comment: This looks great- I'll try it when I get a chance and mark it as the answer if it works!